# SQL WHERE IN - Reporting services an error has occurred during report processing. Incorrect syntax near ','

Tags: sql-server, sql, ssrs

No estoy acostumbrado a trabajar con SSRS, pero por requisitos de un proyecto me encuentro con esta necesidad.
Estoy creando un report en el cual necesito listar una serie de áreas de trabajo y el resultado es un filtro multiárea para que se pueda selecionar, uno, varios o todos.
El problema viene a la hora de seleccionar más de un filtro. Cuando selecciono dos o más casillas, me aparece el siguiente mensaje de error a la hora de generar el informe:

*"An error occurred during local report processing. An error has occurred during report processing. Query execution failed for Dataset 'Eventos'. Incorrect syntax near ','."*

La Query que realizo contra el Dataset 'Eventos', es la siguiente:

```
 IF @TipoEvento=1
         BEGIN
            SELECT  [Alarm_Id] 
                ,[Start_Time]
                ,[NombreTag] 
                ,[Descrip]
                ,[Areas]
                ,[Nuevo]
                ,[Anterior]
                ,[Username]
            FROM VW005_Events_Def
            WHERE 
            Areas IN
                (SELECT [AlarmArea] FROM [FIXALARMS].[dbo].[TB001_ZonaArea]     Where [Zona] IN (@zona))
            AND (Start_Time BETWEEN @StartTime AND DATEADD(s, 1, @EndTime)) AND  
            AND (Descrip LIKE '%'+@fdesc+'%') 
            AND ((NombreTag NOT LIKE '%_SPAN') OR (NombreTag NOT LIKE '%_OFFSET') 
                  OR (NombreTag NOT LIKE '%_WIRE'))
            AND (Descrip NOT LIKE '%AlmODBC%')
        
            ORDER BY Start_Time
         END
            
       ELSE
         BEGIN
            
            SELECT [Alarm_Id]
                  ,[Start_Time]
                  ,[NombreTag]
                  ,[Descrip]
                  ,[Areas]
                  ,[Nuevo]
                  ,[Anterior]
                  ,[Username]
              FROM VW005_Events_Def
            WHERE Areas IN
                (SELECT [AlarmArea] FROM [FIXALARMS].[dbo].[TB001_ZonaArea]     Where [Zona] IN (@zona))     
            AND   (Start_Time BETWEEN @StartTime AND DATEADD(s, 1, @EndTime)) 
            AND (Descrip LIKE '%'+@fdesc+'%') 
            AND ((NombreTag LIKE '%_SPAN') OR (NombreTag LIKE '%_OFFSET') 
                  OR (NombreTag LIKE '%_WIRE'))
            AND (Descrip NOT LIKE '%AlmODBC%')
            ORDER BY Start_Time
            
         END
```

Para el caso que nos toca, @TipoEvento es igual a 1.
Si ejecuto la parte de la Query que me interesa en SQL funciona correctamente, y si tan sólo marco UN filtro, también funciona. Me da la sensación que no "separa" las comas intermedias del "listado" que busco previamente.

Un saludo y gracias por adelantado.

Comment: `zona` es un campo numerico o de texto? Puede que @zona contenga valores de texto sin comillas (ej: a,b,c en vez de 'a','b','c')

Comment: Es un campo de texto. Los valores de esto lo obtengo haciendo la Query: "SELECT DISTINCT Zona
FROM            TB001_ZonaArea" y la columna Zona es de tipo nvarchar(20). Eso que comentas de las comillas es lo que me parece que está sucediendo, pero no sé donde debería añadirlas para que las tenga en cuenta.

Answer (score 0):

Las cláusulas IN son complicadas con las variables, por lo que se necesita una forma distinta de proceder. Crear una variable de tipo tabla con las @zonas:

```
DECLARE @zonas TABLE (list varchar(25)) 
INSERT into @zonas
SELECT DISTINCT Zona FROM TB001_ZonaArea
```

Y ajustar el WHERE

```
WHERE [Zona] in ( select list from @zonas )
```

Otra forma mas directa, si la seleccion no requiere un proceso muy complicado:

```
WHERE [Zona] in ( SELECT DISTINCT Zona FROM TB001_ZonaArea WHERE condition1=value1 )
```

Comment: La segunda propuesta no me serviría porque hago una lista de una lista, con una condición no abarco todo, y necesito que esto sea variable en número de condiciones. Probaré la primera opción a ver que tal. En cuanto lo pruebe, comento el resultado.